# How can I create an online pdf merger for my website?

Tags: php, html, pdf, fpdf

Here are a couple of website examples:

- http://www.pdfmerge.com/
- http://www.pdfmerger.org/en/

Is this simple or difficult coding? Can this be accomplished with fpdf?

Comment: Do you want to implement the actual merging software or just provide a frontend which will take the documents and call other merging software on the server then return the merged document. The former would require learning the PDF format and implementing parts of it, the latter would just be learning how your language handles file uploads and calling external programs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if fpdf can do this. But if you are doing this on linux you could just make your script use ghostscript to merge the files uploaded. It would be something like

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=out.pdf uploaded1.pdf uploaded2.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you handle it.

I would suggest just using [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) on the server to merge the files, and send them to the client for downloading.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the website [SimplyPDF.org](http://www.simplypdf.org/index.html) is a startup which is going to offer exactly what you need. However, they seem to be in the process of creating their website.